# Is GSDAppIndexing SDK required anymore?

Tags: ios, firebase-app-indexing

It seems like for iOS 9+, Implementing Universal links (associated-domains, apple-app-site-associations) is enough for Google App indexing. The GSDAppIndexing pod (2.0.3) is not required anymore. Is that correct?

I ask because on the japanese product forum, a googler said that the SDK should be [removed from the app](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmaster-ja/2fB6nv_bTq4).

Similarly, the [firebase app-indexing setup page for iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/ios/app) doesn't mention the SDK anymore and simply says to implement universal links.

Just need a confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your question. GSDAppIndexing pod isn't required anymore. Implementing Universal Links is sufficient for Firebase App Indexing.